# Jenkins pipeline for Spring boot project which uses JIB to create and push docker image to docker hub

Tags: jenkins, jib

I am working on creating a Jenkins pipeline which will build the and push the docker image to public docker repository.

To create docker image, i am using jib plugin (configured in pom.xml).

If jib is commented in pom.xml, jenkins build is successful but after uncommenting jib plugin, jenkins build fail.

`pom.xml`

Part of pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <docker.repo>aditya9827</docker.repo>
        <docker.tag>${project.version}</docker.tag>
        <docker.registry>registry.hub.docker.com</docker.registry>
        <docker.name>${docker.registry}/${docker.repo}/${project.build.finalName}:${docker.tag}</docker.name>
    </properties>
```

Plugin section of POM

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:17-jdk-slim</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>${project.artifactId}</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Jenkins pipeline

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools{
        maven "MAVEN"
    }
    
    stages{
        stage('Maven Build'){
            steps{
                checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/aditya9827/micro']])
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
        stage('Docker build '){
            steps{
                withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'github-creds', variable: 'docker-hub')]) {
                sh 'mvn jib:build'
}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

stage (maven build) run successfully but failed in docker build stage.

`Jenkins console log`

```
mvn jib:build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] licensing-service                                                  [jar]
[INFO] micro-parent                                                       [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.org:licensing-service >----------------------
[INFO] Building licensing-service 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT                          [1/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jib-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build (default-cli) @ licensing-service ---
[WARNING] 'mainClass' configured in 'maven-jar-plugin' is not a valid Java class: ${start-class}
[INFO] 
[INFO] Containerizing application to licensing-service...
[WARNING] Base image 'openjdk:17-jdk-slim' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
[INFO] Getting manifest for base image openjdk:17-jdk-slim...
[INFO] Building dependencies layer...
[INFO] Building resources layer...
[INFO] Building jvm arg files layer...
[INFO] Building classes layer...
[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry-1.docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry.hub.docker.com

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: index.docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[INFO] The base image requires auth. Trying again for openjdk:17-jdk-slim...
[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry-1.docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: registry.hub.docker.com

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: index.docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[WARNING] The credential helper (docker-credential-desktop) has nothing for server URL: docker.io

Got output:

credentials not found in native keychain

[INFO] Using base image with digest: sha256:aaa3b3cb27e3e520b8f116863d0580c438ed55ecfa0bc126b41f68c3f62f9774
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] licensing-service 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT ................... FAILURE [ 11.732 s]
[INFO] micro-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-29T14:50:26+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build (default-cli) on project licensing-service: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/library/licensing-service' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for registry-1.docker.io/library/licensing-service: 401 Unauthorized
[ERROR] HEAD https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/licensing-service/blobs/sha256:f24515035a9c9032d08dd7578dfccc4c24f25be1072f1ebc8112f7ef15759583
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```